# eclipse Failed to load properties file for project

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'v just installed eclipse for developing android applications on my macbook pro(10.9).I'v installed jdk1.7,android sdk and adt plugin for eclipse,however,when i create my first android application , i got the error  'Failed to load properties file for project ...'

Error Log：
    !SESSION 2015-03-10 09:08:33.363 -----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
    java.version=1.7.0_75
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=zh_CN
    Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring    /Users/bwiunbuaa/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
    Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product  org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/bwiunbuaa/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2015-03-10 09:09:57.105
!MESSAGE Failed to load properties file for project 'lighthouse'
```

what is wrong for me?

Comment: Stop. Use Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

follow steps for updating eclipse

```
 1. Download Eclipse from the official site
 2. Download and install JDK latest version
 3. After installing the eclipse, go to Help > Install New Software.
 4. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
 5. In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the
Name and the following URL for the Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
Click OK.
 6. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
 7. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
 8. Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
 9. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.
```