# failed to load properties file for project Android studio already installed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I have already installed android studio and is working great. Then I downloaded Eclipse Neon tar.gz file from the official website and ran the installer. When it prompted me to choose which installation i gave Android development and the installation process finished.

Soon after it finished, the ide opened in a given workspace. Then the error came as no ddms found. I closed eclipse and opened android studio to check if its working fine or not. Its working fine and the last project loaded without any error. S

So I closed it and opened eclipse again. But before closing it i opened android emulator from android studio. I left it there so that i can use it for eclipse.

When i opened Eclipse again, it told me that no avd found. I closed it and stared creating a new Android application project. From `File->New->Android Application Project` In the last screen when i clicked finish, Errors came in the problems tab and a error report was generated by the eclipse.

The problem is that no matter how many times i click finish the wizard wont close. I can only cancel the wizard.

This is the error came `failed to load properties file for project` for my project

I searched it and found many links. One solution was to delete debug keystore,

Other was 
[eclipse Failed to load properties file for project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955149/eclipse-failed-to-load-properties-file-for-project)

Other was to Deleting the existing ADT Bundle and Extract the new ADT Bundle.

My worry is the I already have android studio installed in my system. I that going to be a problem?

And also when i checked for paths of SDK location its correct. Both Android Studio and Eclipse are sharing the same.

So what should i do. Pleeeez help